# selenium Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, parrot

Изучал парсеры на питоне дошел до селениума. И тут началось...

В начале мне выдавало ошибку (Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible)

Перепробовал 3 версии geckodriver 11.1 17.0 21.1(последнюю) (Linux 64bit)

Скачал распаковал и отправил распакованный файл в /usr/local/bin
(когда пробовал разные версии то удалял старые и ставил новые)

Толку 0, таже ошибка. Далее зашел cd ~/.mozilla/firefox, делитнул оттуда 
profiles.ini, перезапустил Firefox, тот же результат.

На нервах переустановил Firefox - эффект нулевой.

Попытался запустить с правами админа - выдало другой TraceBack:

Что интересно показывается разный TraceBack, когда я запускаю с sudo и без него.

Может, кто сталкивался с подобным.

ОS Parrot Security (Linux 64 bit)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible` -> https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/1096084

Comment: Если вы редактировали файлы стандартного профиля, то вероятнее всего то, что Firefox не может записать изменения в какой-нибудь файл, из-за того что при редактировании вы изменили права доступа на запись в файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В скриптах селениума старайтесь не использовать стандартный профиль.

Лучшее решение в таком случае - создать отдельный профиль.
Новый профиль можно создать Firefox'ом, а можно просто создать папку возле скрипта:

Создайте папку вашего профиля. В саму папку положите/создайте файл "times.json", содержание в котором такое:

```
{
"created": 1540213891527
}
```

Где цифры - это время создания профиля в эпохе. Можете просто скопировать это))

Далее, в скрипте, указываете место профиля при запуске Firefox:

```
ub_profile = 'название_папки_профиля'
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(ub_profile)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

И пользуетесь)))
К примеру я ещё копирую в папку `название_папки_профиля/extensions/` нужное мне расширение. И тогда браузер запустится с этим расширением.

Когда профиль создаётся Firefox'ом, то имя папки профиля будет иметь вид `"случайная_последовательность.имя_профиля"` - `eviespx1.UB` - случайная последовательность нужна для уникальности профиля. Если создавать профиль вручную, вам этого делать не нужно, просто назовите папку так, как будет понятно вам))

Comment: UB это имя нового профиля в Firefox? Просто я создал пользователя через FireFox сохранил в каталоге No such file or directory: 'selenium_profile.selenium'
 скрипта, создал файл times.json Но при исполнении, выходит ошибка  No such file or directory: 'selenium_profile.selenium'. selenium_profile это папка с профилем, selenium имя профиля.

Comment: Прошу прощения, скомкал в один ответ несколько разных мыслей))) Подправил ответ, надеюсь станет понятно)))

Comment: У вас папка с профилем лежит рядом со скриптом, а в ней times.json ?